# Where was the 1952 movie "Hong Kong" filmed?

Tags: film-location, hong-kong-1952

Where was the movie "[Hong Kong (1952)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043654/)" starring Ronald Reagan filmed? Were the Hong Kong scenes actually filmed in Hong Kong?

The tram "ding ding" looks and sounds real to me and some of the shots of the harbor and city look fairly authentic. I didn't think a B-movie would have the budget or care enough to make a realistic looking set.

Comment: Why do you think they might have been filmed on location rather than in Hollywood?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod updated with why I thought it might be filmed in the city.

Comment: Do the shots in question include any of the stars? It could be stock footage. Since such footage isn't filmed as part of the movie, where it comes from doesn't constitute a filming location per se.

Comment: Yea I don't recall :) Some of the stuff at the very beginning is almost certainly stock footage.

Answer (score 1):

IMDB shows only one filming location, and it's [in Hollywood](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043654/locations?ref_=tt_ql_dt_6). I suspect this information is complete and correct; it was less common to travel to distant locations to film Hollywood actors in that era.